# Can't create a user in MongoDB, following instructions on their site

Tags: mongodb

Trying to follow [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) tutorial, but when I press enter after typing out step 3 I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: createUser is not defined

So I tried changing out createUser to addUser but then I get this error:

> Roles must be non-empty strings

So I tried deleting the db part of the embedded role document to make it into one string, but then I got this conflicting error:

> Roles must be an array when present in system.users entries

After a quick search the only thing I could turn up on google was the source code [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/auth/user_document_parser.cpp).

From what I can tell, if this is the correct version of the source code then something is going wrong between lines 65 and 76.

What do I need to do?

Comment: What version of mongo are you using?

Comment: 2.4.10, going to update and try again. Apparently trying to update via the .msi package they provide doesn't do anything.

Comment: `createUser` does not exist in 2.4. Try to follow [a tutorial for the relevant version you have](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/enable-authentication/).